# What is the alternative class for AsyncFacebookRunner and also Facebook in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

What is the alternative class for AsyncFacebookRunner and also Facebook in Facebook SDK. These are deprecated. What are the current Classes and where can i get the documentation for the latest SDK?

Comment: Hi @Santhosh The Facebook gave the SDK for the Android. Go to the developer.facebook.com and check the Android SDK for the Facebook.I think i will help you

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-3.x#20to30. It says

> AsyncFacebookRunner has been deprecated; to execute Requestst
>   asynchronously, use RequestAsyncTask [...]

Comment: Thanks For the Reply. And it helped a lot. Thanks Again